# How can I uninstall just one instance of a program using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have a program that's installed in two separate file paths, one in AppData and one in Program Files x86. I'd like to write a PowerShell script that finds and uninstalls only the one in AppData while leaving the one in Program Files intact. These two instances of the program are the same version and have the same name under Get-WmiObject, so I'm not sure how to identify by file path. I could simply delete the folder with Remove-Item but this wouldn't achieve the same result as Uninstall, to my knowledge. Advise appreciated, thanks!

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/uninstall-package?view=powershell-7.2 would it be possible to use that

Comment: This seems promising, and I do see the -Destination parameter to specify a path, but I'm unsure what the syntax would look like. Would it be as simple as Uninstall-Package -Destination [File Path]? Running this returns "Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters"